# How to collate OnSuccess of multiple Future object in Scala

Tags: scala

The following code simulates on line shopping by using print statements. I am using Future to simulate a scenario in which I add multiple items to a shopping basket concurrently (I am adding every even number item in the basket). I want that in the end, the code prints how many items have been added to the basket.

1. I create 5 Future objects (so I expect result to be 5)
2. I store each Future in a List.
3. I use for loop to wait for completion of each Future
4. I want that after all Futures have executed, I pick their
   Success object and collate their values (add them). This is the part
   I am unable to code.

   ```
   import scala.concurrent._
   import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
   import scala.util.{Failure,Success}


   object ConcurrencyExample extends App {

     //simulation of backend process of adding an object in basket
     def addToBaskset(id:Int): Future[Int] = {
       Future {
         println("adding item "+id+" to shopping basket")
         Thread.sleep(10) //simulate backend process delay
         println("Item "+ id +" added")
         1 //simulate the no. of items in basket
       }
     }

     //simulate shopping. Pick even numbers and add them to baskset
     def simulateShopping(count:Int):List[Future[Int]] = {
       def go(c:Int, l:List[Future[Int]]):List[Future[Int]] = {
         println("looking at more items in inventory ")
         if(c == 0) l else
         if (c % 2 == 0)
         {
           Thread.sleep(10)
           go(c-1,addToBaskset(c)::l)
         }
         else {
           Thread.sleep(10)
           go(c-1,l)
         }
       }
       go(10,List())
     }


     val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
     val shoppingList: List[Future[Int]] = List()

     println("start shopping...")
     //simulate shopping of 10 items. Even values will be added to basket using Future. Return list of Future created
     val futures:List[Future[Int]] = simulateShopping(10)

     //wait for each item in list to finish. Its results will be collected in a new list called 'result'
     val result = for (i<- futures) yield i //we will get Success(1), 5 times

     println("finished shopping. result: " +result)

     **//how to I get a single integer value which is sum of all Success values?**
   //result seem to be a  List of Success() (not Future), so I tried using foldLeft or map but the code doesn't compile if I use them. I keep getting error for Unit value.


   }
   ```

Result

```
start shopping...
looking at more items in inventory 
looking at more items in inventory 
adding item 10 to shopping basket
Item 10 added
looking at more items in inventory 
adding item 8 to shopping basket
looking at more items in inventory 
Item 8 added
looking at more items in inventory 
looking at more items in inventory 
adding item 6 to shopping basket
Item 6 added
looking at more items in inventory 
adding item 4 to shopping basket
looking at more items in inventory 
Item 4 added
looking at more items in inventory 
looking at more items in inventory 
adding item 2 to shopping basket
Item 2 added
looking at more items in inventory 
finished shopping. result: List(Success(1), Success(1), Success(1), Success(1), Success(1))
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Following code seem to work but why do I have to treat elements of result as Future[Int] when the print shows they are Success(1)?

```
//y seem to be Future[Int]
//y.value is Option(Success(1))
//v.get is calling 'get' on Success
val total = result.foldLeft(0)((x,y)=>y.value match {
    case Some(v)=>x+v.get
    case None=>x
  })
  println("finished shopping. result: " +result + "total "+total)


finished shopping. result: List(Success(1), Success(1), Success(1), Success(1), Success(1))total 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Future.sequence` to turn `List[Future[Int]]` to `Future[List[Int]]` and then call `sum` to see all items have been added:

```
val result: Int = Await.result(Future.sequence(futures).map(_.sum), 5 seconds)
```

Note that `Await.result` is only used so that the test won't prematurely terminate without all the futures completing.

> why do I have to treat elements of result as Future[Int] when the
>   print shows they are Success(1)?

Because `Future[T].value` returns an `Option[Try[T]]`, where `Try` can be either `Success` or `Failure`. But it will only return a value if the future is complete. I wouldn't go down a path using `.value` at all.

Comment: Hi, I do not need length but sum of return values of Success. I have edited my question with an approach which worked but I am confused why I got a list of Future[Int] when the print shows I have a list of Success(1)

Comment: @ManuChadha I originally wrote `sum` but wasn't sure if that's what you wanted. I've edited the answer.

Comment: @ManuChadha Youre for comprehension would yield a `Seq[Future[Int]]`, similar to my answer using `Future.sequence`. But as it currently looks, you're not actually waiting on the completion of the futures. Calling `Future[T].get` is definitely not the recommended approach.

Comment: Wouldn't 'val result = for (i<- futures) yield i' wait for completion of futures? The online examples I have seen seem to use 'for(result<-SomeFuture)' but do not use 'await'.

Comment: @ManuChadha No, it doesn't. It's equivalent to calling `result.map(identity)`. There's no implicit waiting for completion.

Comment: OK. Is there a better way than to guess the time (5 seconds in your answer) it might take for Futures to finish their job? Your approach also seem to block the execution, am I correct?

Comment: @ManuChadha Yes, it blocks the execution, that's why I've written that it is only for the sake of the test. In production, you simply do whatever you need by composing on the future's result.

Comment: where is Future.sequence defined? Coming back to my earlier comment regarding whether for will wait for all Futures to finish, maybe I wasn't clear in my comment. I understand that the main process will not wait for 'for' loop to finish. But assuming that the main process does not end, the for loop itself will wait for all futures to finish. In example 'for(i<-futures) yield i', the yield will happen when all futures have finished, correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131837/discussion-between-manu-chadha-and-yuval-itzchakov).

Answer (score 1):

```
Future.foldLeft(futures)(0)(_ + _).foreach(result => "finished shopping. result: " +result)
```